# There is a white line on the right side of middle of the GUI screen

Tags: python, user-interface, python-turtle, pong

I am making a **Pong game program** using **Python**. There is a **white line in the middle of the screen**, which I can't figure out why is there.
I am pasting my code and the output (the issue) below.

```py
import turtle

wm = turtle.Screen()
wm.title("Pong by Tharv")
wm.bgcolor("black")
# wm.setup(width=800, hieght=300)
wm.tracer(0)

# Bat A

batA = turtle.Turtle()
batA.speed(0)
batA.shape("square")
batA.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
batA.color("white")
batA.penup()
batA.goto(-350, 0)

# Bat B

batB = turtle.Turtle()
batB.speed(0)
batB.shape("square")
batB.color("white")
batB.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
batB.penup
batB.goto(350, 0)


# Ball

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)


# maingameloop

while True:
    wm.update()
```

[image: The Issue]

I have tried commenting out each line of code for the 'batB' (refer to the code please.) , but still can't understand why is there a white line in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot parentheses in your call to `batB.penup`, so the pen isn't actually raised, causing a line to be drawn when you move back to the center.
Add parentheses and it should work.

```
# Bat B

batB = turtle.Turtle()
batB.speed(0)
batB.shape("square")
batB.color("white")
batB.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
batB.penup  # Should be penup()
batB.goto(350, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add parentheses in Bat B in `batB.penup`